# How to force Android clients to unbind from a remote service

Tags: android, android-service

I am writing a remote Android service that will be bound to by many other developers who write apps. I see that if too many remote clients connect or some abusive clients forget to disconnect from my service then my process can run out of native resources and the virtual machine will send a signal to my process and kill it. I want to protect my app from such a situation by recording the connections from each app by pid or uid and if too many connections are made from a particular app force the connection to be dropped so resources are released. Any ideas on if or how to achieve this?

The SIGABRT looks like this:

```
pid: 6394, tid: 6539, name: Binder_3  >>> com.my.app <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------

#00  pc 00021f98  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01  pc 00013075  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
#02  pc 00013289  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03  pc 00011f57  /system/lib/libc.so
#04  pc 0002184c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05  pc 00045fd7  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+78)
#06  pc 0004d723  /system/lib/libdvm.so
#07  pc 0004fff9  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#08  pc 00071b07  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::javaObjectForIBinder(_JNIEnv*, android::sp<android::IBinder> const&)+174)
#09  pc 0006affb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#10  pc 0001de8c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#11  pc 0004e46b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#12  pc 000272a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
#13  pc 0002e31c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#14  pc 0002b980  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#15  pc 00060905  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#16  pc 0004d1d1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
#17  pc 0006cceb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#18  pc 00070eef  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#19  pc 00019269  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::BBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+60)
#20  pc 0001d80b  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::executeCommand(int)+490)
#21  pc 0001db9b  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+38)
#22  pc 0001dc11  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48)
#23  pc 00021a35  /system/lib/libbinder.so
#24  pc 0000ea61  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
#25  pc 0004d159  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
#26  pc 0000e593  /system/lib/libutils.so
#27  pc 0000d1b0  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#28  pc 0000d348  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
```

And in logcat I see:

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): global reference table overflow (max=51200)
JNI global reference table (0x6dae5008) dump:
  Last 10 entries (of 51200):
    51199: 0x430a3398 java.lang.ref.WeakReference
    51198: 0x430a3348 android.os.RemoteCallbackList$Callback
    51197: 0x430a32b8 java.lang.ref.WeakReference
    51196: 0x430a3268 android.os.RemoteCallbackList$Callback
    51195: 0x430a3038 java.lang.ref.WeakReference
    51194: 0x430a31d8 java.lang.ref.WeakReference
    51193: 0x430a2f58 java.lang.ref.WeakReference
    51192: 0x430a2f08 android.os.RemoteCallbackList$Callback
    51191: 0x430a2e78 java.lang.ref.WeakReference
    51190: 0x430a2e28 android.os.RemoteCallbackList$Callback
  Summary:
      223 of java.lang.Class (191 unique instances)
        2 of java.lang.String (2 unique instances)
    25487 of java.lang.ref.WeakReference (25487 unique instances)
        1 of android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
        8 of android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver (8 unique instances)
        1 of android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$InnerConnection
       30 of android.content.ContentProvider$Transport (30 unique instances)
        5 of android.database.ContentObserver$Transport (5 unique instances)
        1 of android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayManagerCallback
        1 of android.opengl.EGLDisplay
        1 of android.opengl.EGLSurface
        1 of android.opengl.EGLContext
        1 of com.my.app.MyClass$1
        1 of com.android.dex.Dex
        1 of com.my.app.MyBinder
    25436 of android.os.RemoteCallbackList$Callback (25436 unique instances)
Failed adding to JNI global ref table (51200 entries)
```

Comment: I appear to be running out of `WeakReferences` and `RemoteCallbackList$Callback` objects. I use the `RemoteCallbackList` class to track callbacks to invoke so I think I could write my own `RemoteCallbackList` to track `Callback` objects from each PID and start dropping them if a PID has too many. I'm not sure about the `WeakReferences`, I need to more complete heap dump to see where those objects live.